# Geting the data from different table next to a CONCAT-ed data

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicate-data

I have following query:

```
SELECT date, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', nombre, start, end, posicion)) schedule
  FROM dias, empleados
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date ASC
```

And I get following result:

```
1376542800  Tesar|12:00|16:00|Cocina,Levina|12:00|16:00|Cocina...
1376629200  Levina|12:00|14:00|Barra,Peter|11:00|14:00|Cocina,...
1376715600  Raquel|12:00|14:00|Barra,Tesar|12:00|14:00|Barra,L...
1376802000  Tom|12:00|14:00|Barra,Raquel|10:00|11:00|Barra,Pet...
1376888400  Tesar|12:00|14:00|Barra,Levina|12:00|14:00|Barra,T..
```

Basically everything gets group together and get duplicated:
How can I get the following result:

```
1376542800  Tesar|12:00|16:00|Cocina
1376629200  Tom|12:00|14:00|Barra,Tesar|11:00|14:00|Cocina
1376715600  Tom|12:00|14:00|Barra
1376802000  Tom|12:00|14:00|Barra,Levina|10:00|11:00|Barra
1376888400  Tom|12:00|14:00|Barraç
                PEter
                Mike
                MArko
```

Basically to get all the names (also they don't have a matching date,start,end) from the "empoleados" column from the different table and display it anyway.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your query does not make sense.  Where is the field `date` coming from?  Why is there is join condition between the two tables?

Comment: "nombre, start, end, posicion" column are coming from dias, and only " nombre" is coming from "empleados " table. There is no JOIN. I want to have a populated table with all the name regardless do the have or not have data connected to them.

Answer (score 0):

If `nombre` is coming from both tables, then that is probably the join key you want.  It would seem that you also want a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT d.date,
       coalesce(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', d.nombre, d.start, d.end, d.posicion)), e.nombre) schedule
  FROM empleados e left outer join
       dias d
       on e.nombre = d.nombre
GROUP BY date,
         (case when date is NULL then e.nombre end)
ORDER BY date ASC ;
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow respons. I pretty much get the same result. All the data gets bunch up together.